# Jupyter/Plotly - how to replace or update plot from add_trace?

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, plotly

Consider this Jupyter Python code, which uses Plotly:

```python
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import display
import random

mybutton = widgets.Button(description="Redraw")

xs = np.linspace(start=0, stop=10, num=100)

fig = go.FigureWidget( layout=go.Layout() )

# NB: function needs to be written in a way, that returns np.array for input np.array!
# or - use np.vectorize, to apply it element-by-element
def TestFunc(inval):
    return inval+2*random.random()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=xs, y=np.vectorize(TestFunc)(xs),
                    mode='lines',
                    name='Test'))

def on_button_clicked(b):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=xs, y=np.vectorize(TestFunc)(xs),
                        mode='lines',
                        name='Test'))

mybutton.on_click(on_button_clicked)

widgets.VBox([mybutton, fig])
```

What I want to do, is redraw the function anew, whenever I click the button. However, since I use `add_trace` in the button callback, I get new traces added - I don't get the original one replaced:

[image: jupyter_add_trace.gif]

So, my question is:

- How do I obtain a reference to a "trace", added with `add_trace`, so that I could replace it? (say, `fig.traces[0] = ...`)
- What is the best way to redraw the figure with a new retrace, with the minimal amount of object instantiation (I guess, I could do `fig = go.FigureWidget( ... ) ...` upon each button click, but that would have to recreate *everything*; I'd think, just recreating the `y` array, and triggering a redraw would be more "optimized")

Answer (score 3):

OK, found something - still not sure if this is the way to do it, so if someone knows better, please post...

But anyways, `fig.add_trace` returns a reference that you can store in a variable; eventually that variable also contains the .x and .y arrays, and the .y array can be directly replaced, like so:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import display
import random

mybutton = widgets.Button(description="Redraw")

xs = np.linspace(start=0, stop=10, num=100)

fig = go.FigureWidget( layout=go.Layout() )

# NB: function needs to be written in a way, that returns np.array for input np.array!
# or - use np.vectorize, to apply it element-by-element
def TestFunc(inval):
    return inval+2*random.random()

mytrace = fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=xs, y=np.vectorize(TestFunc)(xs),
                    mode='lines',
                    name='Test'))
print(repr(mytrace))

def on_button_clicked(b):
    mytrace.data[0].y = np.vectorize(TestFunc)(xs)

mybutton.on_click(on_button_clicked)

widgets.VBox([mybutton, fig])
```

The above code works as intended - but I'm not yet sure whether it's the most optimized way to do it...

Comment: This doesn't work in the case where you different length traces.  If my traces are cities in a TSP tour and in one trace there are 3 cities and another there are five cities, you are SOL.

Note that in the case of map-based data, there's not issue of horizontal scale changing based on the number of cities visited.  The map is the map and the tour is the tour.